# Postfix: Illegal address from unknown sender

Tags: postfix, email-server

I got this alert from my maillog postfix

> mail postfix/smtpd[13563]: warning: hostname riservata.miami19.mia.seabone.net does not resolve to address 195.22.199.54: Name or service not known

Do you think this is a security concern?

How to prevent this to happen again.

TIA

Comment: Is that your IP address?

Comment: It is neither my vps ip nor my public internet ip

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's not really a security concern, it's just a misconfiguration of reverse DNS of the remote host connecting to the Postfix daemon. It cannot be prevented, at least not by anything you can do.

More details: When a remote client connects to Postfix, the daemon wants to put in the logs the IP address of the remote client (which it gets by looking up the peer of the TCP socket) AND also the hostname of the remote client. So it does a DNS query like this to get the hostname from the IP address:

```
$ host 195.22.199.54
54.199.22.195.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer riservata.miami19.mia.seabone.net.
```

However, before Postfix will "believe" that hostname is really the true DNS name of the remote client, it does a double check, looking up the hostname in the DNS to see if it resolves to the same IP:

```
$ host riservata.miami19.mia.seabone.net
Host riservata.miami19.mia.seabone.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

And then since it can't get the hostname lookup and reverse lookup to match, it issues that warning in the logs.

Some sites refuse to accept email from remote clients that exhibit this problem. If you want to join them you can turn on [reject_unknown_client_hostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unknown_client_hostname) in your Postfix config.